# See me from your view point - As seen by the rest

Tags: riddle, science

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

See me from bottom, I am just a wave.

> Hint : This is my lucky number <- 151208

Comment: 250 pts bounty after 2 days to the person with all lines and hint cracked.

Comment: 500points if any one answers before bounty is announced .

Comment: Yeah ... :P  BTW quite Interesting puzzle .. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I have cracked it :D

> It is bluetooth

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

> It seems like specs with 2 handle and  and 2 glasses as per shape of bluetooth

See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.

> From the right it looks like butterfly with 2 moustaches :D

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

> It connect to just one Bluetooth device

See me from bottom, I am just a wave.

> It about Bluetooth waves

Hint :

This is my lucky number <- 151208

> IEEE 802.15.1

Hint 2 : Its related to technology

> Obviously It is wireless technology

Hint 3 : Its in your mobile

> Its available in mobile

Bluetooth Icon

> [image]

Comment: Bingo ...at last ...super ..Give this guy ..a Medal

Comment: Or at least a bounty. XD

Comment: And I am waiting for bounty points ... ;)

Answer (score 8):

Update (answer 2)

> Still is abstract but at least an object. Related to technology. Additionally, has an item number 151208 !  See the NATO plug socket, the glasses (spectacles) and the butterfly shape on the two sides, from above you see the connection itself, and from below, if there is a connection and the cover is tilted down, you only see the wavy margin of the cover.

We could be on a...

> wedding. 
>  
> The two *sides* seen from the opposite direction: The bride looks *spectacular*, the groom wears a *butterfly* bow.
>  
> From the *bottom*: only waves of the long wedding dress can be seen.  
>  
> From the *top*: you see them connected together, hands in hands.  
>  
> (The lucky word is 15-1-20-8 "oath")

The "science" tag makes me think that this solution is 90% wrong, I have a feeling the asker is looking for some kind of electrotechnical object, and the "wormhole" was a closer shot.!

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfnfM.jpg)

Comment: Nope ...not this one ..

Answer (score 8):

Another guess, following from the 'science'. tag.  Are you a:

> Electron orbital group (specifically, 'd')?
> [image]

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

> You would see two lobes connected

See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.

> 4 orbs in a butterfly-ish shape

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

> Again, only two lobes, giving a single (visible) axis. I'm rusty on the science, but this could refer to a single ligand axis, or the fact that it looks like a lower level orbital from this view?

See me from bottom, I am just a wave.

> Not sure how directionality plays in yet, but this could reference the wave/particle duality of electrons?

Comment: Nice ..but no ...use the hint ..

Answer (score 5):

> Letter **B**

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

> From left it looks like spectacles

See me from right, I appear as butterfly.

> From right it looks like shape of butterfly.

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

> From the top it look like one line

See me from bottom, I just a wave.

> From Bottom we can see curve of `B`

Comment: Something similar...Keep guessing..use the hint

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer

> Number 8? From left it looks like spectacles, from right like a butterfly, from top it becomes one line and if you orient it in 3D it can look like a wave.

Comment: Nice try .. but not '8' ..it has to match all lines of riddle.

Answer (score 4):

Could you be ...

> a **whormhole or Einstein–Rosen bridge**?
>
>  **See me from left, I appear as spectacles** : this would refer to the way it is usuaylly represented : from a certain POV, it looks like a pair of googles.
>  **See me from right, I appear as butterfly**. : again, when you turn a little the POV, it looks like a [butterfly](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Lorentzian_Wormhole.svg/220px-Lorentzian_Wormhole.svg.png)
>  **See me from top, I will connect to just one.** : here, I think this is about the function of it : connecting one side to the other (far away) side : two places made one by the bridge
>  **See me from bottom, I just a wave**. I thinks it is about what Wheeler-Misner used to describe them, comparing whormholes creation with the effect of waves breaking against (eg) a cliff, producing bubbles and foam
>
>  Thus, I think that your cardinals were more figurative than litteral

Comment: Interesting ...but not correct ..

Answer (score 4):

This could be

> Beta

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

> Looks like spectacles from left with one handle

See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.

> it look like butterfly if we see it up side down

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

See me from bottom, I am just a wave.

> [image]

Comment: So close ..not this ...but something similar ..use the hint it will be easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, it is referred to

> a frame (of spectacles) - in a shape, formed by 2 semi-circles, joined with a connector.

As, from the left(or for that matter, even from right)- it appears as

> glasses/spects. Here, another angle to interpret the answer is the word - *a _spect_*  - which links and rightly interprets the intent

In science as well, we have a concept of

> *frame* of reference, which - simply put - refers to the aspect/angle/perspective of our view.

And for other lines of the puzzle

> the above-said object appears as different objects when looked from different locations,  such as: from bottom - a ripple, ____, from a side, butterfly with its wings stretched,

Comment: Nope..not this one..

Answer (score 2):

> My Last Guess it **infinity**

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

> Obviously it looks like specs

See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.

> Seems like butterfly

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

> Infinity line connect to just one point. Its endless processes.

See me from bottom, I am just a wave.

> Shape of symbol is like wave

Hint : This is my lucky number <- 15120

> [image]

Comment: Nice try ..but no.. The hint is too specific to the answer ..how number is related to infinity .

Answer (score 2):

Final answer

> delta

See me from left, I appear as spectacles.

> delta from the left starts with "d" which appear as spectacles

See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.

> delta from the right ends with "a" which could look like a butterfly depending on the font

See me from top, I will connect to just one.

> a capital Delta (a change in math) is a triangle which has one point on top

See me from bottom, I am just a wave.

> a lowercase delta (derivative in math) shows a wave function (it's been a while since my last calculus class)

Hint

> 151208 is the postal code for Punjab, India which appears to be on a river delta

Second Answer

> Right hand pointing to the sky with pointer finger - (like a "d" in sign language) 
>  See me from left, I appear as spectacles.
>  hand looks like the side view of glasses 
>  See me from right, I appear as a butterfly.
>  clenched fingers look like a butterfly cocoon on a branch 
>  See me from top, I will connect to just one.
>  one finger is pointing and one point connects to one thing 
>  See me from bottom, I am just a wave.
>  a person observing from below may just see a hand raised and think you're waving 
>  Clue
>  (found by FIreCase) 15-1-20-8 = oath - an oath usually requires one to raise their right hand

Previous answer

> an upside-down capital P

Comment: Nope..not this one

Answer (score 2):

It could be :

> "India" or "The third eye"
>  It fits four lines of the riddle
>  151208 is a postal code in India
>  3:10 today : in 1510, on the 19th of December, Goa, a small Indian region, was conquered
>  As seen from the left, the occidentals see Indians as being smart people(spectacles)
>  As seen from the right, the orientals appreciate India for its landscapes(butterfly)
>  As seen from the top, I will connect to just one(maybe referring to Nepal)
>  As seen from the bottom, I am just a wave(the south part of India has access to the sea/ocean)
>  Therefore, I believe the answer is "India". If not, it could be "The third eye"
>  The link to technology is, in India there's a company called "Third Eye Technologies"

Comment: Nice ...but no...